# C# Button Visibility Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic

I have programatically added several buttons to a C# Form, but only the ones I added via the Designer actually show up. The rest stay invisible even though. I am performing a lot of operations before this; could this perhaps be the cause?

```
public FormView
{
    List<Button> listOfButtons = new List<Button>();
    int frame = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
    {
        listOfButtons.Add(new Button());
    }
    listOfButtons[4 * frame].Width = 92;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame].Height = 92;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame].BackColor = Color.Red;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame].BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("image.png");
    listOfButtons[4 * frame].BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame].ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame].TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame].Location = new Point(1, 0);
    listOfButtons[4 * frame].Click += new EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 1].Width = 92;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 1].Height = 92;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 1].BackColor = Color.Red;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 1].BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("image.png");
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 1].BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 1].ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 1].TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 1].Location = new Point(1, 99);
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 1].Click += new EventHandler(this.button2_Click);

    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 2].Width = 92;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 2].Height = 92;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 2].BackColor = Color.Red;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 2].BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("image.png");
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 2].BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 2].ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 2].TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 2].Location = new Point(99, 0);
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 2].Click += new EventHandler(this.button3_Click);

    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 3].Width = 92;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 3].Height = 92;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 3].BackColor = Color.Red;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 3].BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("image.png");
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 3].BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 3].ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 3].TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 3].Location = new Point(99, 99);
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 3].Click += new EventHandler(this.button4_Click);


    listOfButtons[4 * frame].Visible = true;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 1].Visible = true;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 2].Visible = true;
    listOfButtons[4 * frame + 3].Visible = true;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the the output window?

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as ms-word...But, you want to do your additional actions AFTER InitializeComponent...Also, it does not look like you are actually adding the buttons to any controls? Unless that code is just not listed

Comment: @JustinPihony It's marked as MS Word because it's for a Word add-in. I figured here would be a good place to put it. Moving the Visible=true after the initalize component didn't seem to do anything :/
And yeah, the controls aren't listed.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Everything shows up except the four buttons I create and show here. Any buttons I made in the designer also appear without any issues.

Comment: The biggest problem is that you need to add the buttons to the Control (see my answer below). You can look at the InitializeComponent code for examples. And, the code has nothing to do with MSWord, so I wouldn't tag it as such next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see you adding the buttons to any Parent control.
You should do something like this...

```
Form1.Controls.Add(listOfButtons[4 * frame]); // and so on...
```

Comment: @JakeBloxham, please mark this as the answer considering it fixed the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to but the site told me to wait for five minutes before I could :/
Resolved! Again, thank you so much Rwiti!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all do all this stuff after InitalizeComponent when the controls have been initialized.

Then add your controls to some container on your form. e.g.

```
       yourForm.Controls.Add(controlsToAdd);
```

And if still you are unable to view It may be because of multiple reasons like your buttons are outside the bounds of form or they are overlapping with other controls. Try assigning any one of the buttons you are adding dynamically a fix location within the bounds of the form.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your non-designer controls to the a [Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) collection, either the one of the form, or another control.